# Why the expectation of distance to center of disk is $r/3$ and not $r/2$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

A person throw an arrow on a target of radius $r$. The position of the arrow on the target is uniformly distributed. Let $X$ the distance between the arrow and the center of the circle. The score obtained by a person is $r-X$. What is the average score ? The answer is $\frac{r}{3}$, whereas I found $\frac{r}{2}$ as follow

We have that $X$ is uniform on $[0,r]$. If $Y=r-X$, then $$\mathbb E[Y]=\int_0^r (r-x)f_X(x)dx=\frac{1}{r}\int_0^r (r-x)dx=\frac{r}{2}.$$

Maybe there is a subtlety than I don't see ?

Comment: Why do you think $X$ is uniform on $[0,r]$?

Comment: @5xum : I set $Z=(R\cos \Theta, R\sin \Theta)$ with $R$ uniform on $[0,r]$ and $\Theta$ uniform on $[0,2\pi)$. Then $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}=\mathbb P\{R\leq x, \Theta \in [0,2\pi]\}=\frac{x}{r}.$ It doesn't work ?

Comment: Uniform over the disc *does not* mean the distribution of the distance from the center is uniform.  The probability density of points in a circle sharing a centre with the disc will be inversely proportional to the radius of the circle (if less than $r$), not a constant.$$\dfrac{\mathsf d ~~}{\mathsf d~x}\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)~\propto~\dfrac{1}{x}\mathbf 1_{0< x\leqslant r}$$

Comment: We just had a question like this half a day ago: [Average distance from center of circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3019165/856)

Comment: $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\} = \frac{\pi x^2}{\pi r^2}$ as you are equally likely to land at any point on the area of the board, not equally likely to land at any radial distance from the centre.

Comment: @idm To visualise this, try a simpler version. Suppose score is $1$ if arrow lands within a distance $\frac{r}{2}$ of the centre and $0$ otherwise. Only one quarter of the area of the target is within a distance $\frac{r}{2}$ of the centre, so expected score of an arrow that lands at a random point in the target is $\frac{1}{4}$, not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$F_X(x) = \frac{\pi x^2}{\pi r^2}$$

$$f_X(x)=\frac{2x}{r^2}$$

\begin{align}
E[r-X]&=r-E[X] \\
&=r - \frac1{r^2}\int_0^r 2x^2\, dx\\
&= r - \frac1{r^2}\frac{2r^3}3\\
&= \frac{r}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: I don't get why $F_X(x)=\frac{x^2}{r^2}$

Comment: That is the meaning of uniform over an area, if you draw a circle of the same size on the target, it is equally likely to hit either of them.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you. But if $Z=(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$ with $R$ uniform in $[0,r]$ and $\Theta$ uniform on $[0,2\pi]$, why $$\mathbb P\{|Z|\leq x\}=\mathbb P\{R\leq x,\Theta\in [0,2\pi]\}=\mathbb P\{R\leq x\}=\frac{x}{r}$$ is not true ? I really don't get this point

Comment: the assumption that $R$ is uniform in $[0,r]$ is not valid.

Comment: ok, stange... thank you :)

Comment: @idm say there are 2 points 'a' and 'b' where a is at a distance x1 from center of the circle and b is at a distance of x2 where x1 > x2. Now, the circumference of the circle with radius x1 > than the one with radius x2. Therefore, there are a greater number of points with a distance x1 from the center of the circle than with a distance of x2. So, R is not uniform in [0,r], rather it is more of a probability distribution which increases as we move away from the center of the circle (say f(x) = m*x + c where m>0 and f(x) is the pdf of a point 'x' distance from center of the circle.)

Answer (score 1):

You may first construct the **probability density** as follows:

- At distance $x$ from the center of the circle a corresponding annulus of "thickness" $dx$ has a probability weight of
  $$\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\cdot 2\pi \cdot x \cdot dx$$

So, you get 
$$E(Y) = \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_0^r (r-x)2\pi \cdot x\; dx = \cdots = \frac{r}{3}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{\int_0^r(r-x)x.dx}{\int_0^r x.dx}$$

This gives $r/3$.

The problem with the integral you gave at first, is that the $(r-x)$ needs to be weighted by an $x.dx$, as this is the elemental area of the disc presented by a strip of thickness $dx$ at radius $x$ (or rather $2\pi x.dx$ ... but then the $2\pi$ appears on the top & bottom & *obviously* cancels ... or to put it another way, we could do the calculation for *any sector* of the disc & get the same result) - the *catchment*, if you like, at radius $x$.

Basically you're calculating the mean value of $r-x$ over a sector of a disc, or over a *whole* disc - it makes no difference.